# language is reset to default on any new page load

Tags: magento-2.1, language

I have a multi-language website with a language switcher that actually works. If I click on the new language (e.g, Italian) I'm redirected to a new page with the `?___store=it&___from_store=en` url extension and the contents are translated.

The problem is that when I follow a link from that page, the new page shows the default - initial - language.

What do you think is going wrong?

**edit**

Links to other pages are simple `<a>` tags; is there any function in Magento to build links that consider the selected language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the store should be stored in a cookie called "store" as soon as you change from the default store view.

There are a few possibilities what could go wrong here:

1. The cookie is not saved
2. The store switch based on the cookie is broken
3. your web server always redirects to the default store view (sth. like MAGE_RUN_CODE in the webserver config)

Comment: Hi David, thanks a lot for your answer. Actually it seems the cookie is not saved. Can you pls point me to the code where the cookie is set? I customized the language switcher so maybe I broke something there. Btw I don't see any reference to cookies in `/var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-store/view/frontend/templates/switch/languages.phtml` so maybe I'm not looking at the right code

Comment: the code, which sets the store code cookie, is in the file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php#L565

Comment: It finally seems my problem is related to this issue tracked on github https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6404#issuecomment-245608028. I actually still have problems with it, but your answer pointed me to the right direction, thx a lot :)